# How do I CONCAT a static formula with a changing value based on a cells contents in VBA or an Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My formula is as follows:

```
=(CONCAT("=RSLINX|PLC1!",B3)
```

B3 = VarName1

The goal is to use the RSLINX function with the contents of a changing cell (B3)

I have also tried putting "=RSLINX|PLC1!" in it's own cell to reference as a string, as well as the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCAT("=RSLINX|PLC1",B3))
```

The objective is that B3 can change to a different cell (B4, B5, etc.) so that I can evaluate many different tags quickly, as the only way I've had the RSLINX function work is by manually typing in a correct tag name.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I had to use the original formula:

```
=(CONCAT("=RSLINX|PLC1!",B3)
```

For all desired tags, then copy it and use "Paste Value" and Search & Replace all "RSLINX" with "=RSLINX" in the new columns.